# insert numeric records into ms access from c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, insert, numeric

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTbl ([username],[password],[firstname],[lastname],[mi],[age],[place],[contact])VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
command.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@psw", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@nm", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@mIni", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMI.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@ag", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@plc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPlace.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@cntct", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtContact.Text); ;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblInfo.Visible = true;
lblInfo.Text = "Success";
conn.Close();
```

This gives me the error `Input string was not in a correct format`. Please help me out.

Comment: this code gives me error, input string was not in correct format. So please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Running it through the debugger, which line gives the error?

Comment: Also, take a look at `Int32.TryParse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) as an alternative to `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: Can you share those values which are you passed to perform your task and you found error of "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: Debug and check at what line u r getting the error

Comment: Contact number is usually a 10 digit number, int range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, you might wanna check that

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code, and the error, most likely one of the TextBox control's text (txtContact or txtAge) isn't a valid Integer (whole number) value.  Ensure that you're validating the input.  You should use a RequiredFieldValidator, and either a RangeValidator or RegularExpressionValidator to ensure that the Textbox is not empty and contains valid text.

You might also consider using [System.Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of Convert.ToInt32.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting non integer value to integer value, please check `txtAge.Text` and  `txtContact.Text` and their values, they should contain value which convert into integer value.